# What is "android_webview/Default/Web Data"?

Tags: android, caching, view

We have developed an android app that configures the screen in webview.(vuejs)
What happened in webview seems to be saved in cache.

The path is **app_webview/Default/Web Data.**

However, it is not always saved.
When will it be saved?(**How can I debug?**)

Is there no problem deleting the file while running the application?

Answer (score 0):

```
webview.settings.savePassword = false
webview.settings.saveFormData = false
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? If so, can you [edit] the post(s) so that it's more clear what is happening?